# Linked list Bubblesort is not quite right

Tags: c++, linked-list, bubble-sort, singly-linked-list

I'm working on a bubblesort algorithm for a linked list. It's moving the data about, but it's not quite sorting the data properly. For now I'm only worried about linked lists of ints. Where is the issue? Thanks very much.

```
void List::linkedListBubbleSort()
{
    bool swap = true;
    Node * temp = firstNode;
    Node * current;

     if(firstNode == 0)
     {
          cout << "List is empty." << endl;
          return;
     }

     else
     {
         while(swap == true)
         {
             for(current = firstNode; current != NULL && current->next != NULL; current = current->next)
             {
                 if(current->data > current->next->data)
                 {
                     swap = true;
                     temp->data = current->data;
                     current->data = current->next->data;
                     current->next->data = temp->data;
                 }
             else
             swap = false;
             }

         }
```

Comment: I wouldn't check a pointer against 0. `nullptr` is probably better, even than NULL.

Comment: You cannot use an existing node as a temporary holder for swaps.

Comment: @n.m. Should I store current->data in an int instead?

Comment: Yes, try that. Also, `else swap=false` is not correct, you should do `swap=false` before the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use while(swap==true) because at some point where if(current->data>current->next->data) return false then your upper loop while (swap==true) will not let you iterate further on.

```
    else
    {
         for(current = firstNode; current != NULL && current->next != NULL; current = current->next)
         {
             if(current->data > current->next->data)
             {
                 temp->data = current->data;
                 current->data = current->next->data;
                 current->next->data = temp->data;
             }

         }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You use temp which points to the first node. As a result, while swapping you corrupt the data.
   2.you stop on first swap, you need to stop only when you finished to pass the entire list and no swap was done.
2. the algorithm is not correct. It should be two loops...search for bubble sort.